# UnhandledPromiseRejection Warning in MERN App when trying to save any file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am currently working in a MERN stack application. Whenever i make any changes in the file and try to save it, it gives error in console as UnhandledPromiseRejection. Due to this any changes made in the file does not reflect.
How can i overcome with this type of error?

I have cloned the project from Git Repo. Attached the Git Repo link in this post.

[MERN App Boilerplate](https://github.com/djizco/mern-boilerplate)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified which part of your code is having the problem but that error generally means that a promise is rejecting but you haven't handled it in case of error.

I searched your code and there were a few times when you had handled promises with **then** but there weren't any **catch** methods in case something is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. By Updated the nodemon to 2.0.7, this error has gone, But the updated content is not displayed. Can you help me with this issue ?

Comment: You mean in your computer? Are you sure you saved it?

Comment: Yes, after updated the nodemon version, i am trying to save the local files, but the latest changes are not reflected. I am following this procedure from the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545093/webpack-watch-and-launching-nodemon